# blog softwares for IIS7 and sql server 2008 back end

Tags: sql, vb.net, iis-7, blogs

I need blog software for IIS7 and a SQL Server 2008 backend. I don't know if this is required, but the application (website) I'm hosting is in asp.net (vb.net). Does anyone have any ideas?

I checked out das blog, and graffiticms and they're very old. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your programming question is?

Comment: there is no programming question, its just something i wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest BlogEnginet.NET.  Check it out here http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/.  It works with IIS7 and SQL Server 08.  It is also one of the most popular Blog Engines out there that run .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go for Blogengine.net. It has lots of features with multiple database support (mysql,sqlserver,sqllite,vistadb). It is also extensible ... lots of plugins are available.